# Hide zoom level in react native maps

Tags: react-native, google-maps

Below zoom levels are by default coming in react native maps in KLIA area :-

[image]

below is the location details:-

```
 if(mapReady) {
      if (mapRef.current) {
        mapRef.current.animateToRegion({
          ...targetRegion,
          latitudeDelta: 0.0035,
          longitudeDelta: 0.0035,
        });
      }
    }
```

Can someone guide how to hide this zoom bar.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the minimum and maximum zoom level in map:

```
<MapView
    //other params
    minZoomLevel={2}  // default => 0
    maxZoomLevel={15} // default => 20
>
</MapView>
```

You can find all the props [here](https://github.com/react-native-maps/react-native-maps/blob/master/docs/mapview.md).